# Not getting any logs written to auth.log, kern.log, syslog or any other log files

Tags: 12.04, log, rsyslog

I am not getting any logs in auth.log, kern.log, syslog or any other log files on my 12.04 ubuntu server. There is also no `rsyslog.conf` if it should be there by default.

How can I debug this & get the log files written normally as they should be ?

## Edit:

I just found that rsyslog was not installed at all by default on my ubuntu 12.04. After installing it via apt-get I can see log files being written.

But is it really like I need to manually install rsyslog to see the logs, otherwise I won't be getting anything in the logs ??

Comment: My 12.04 server came with rsyslog installed and has been writing logs ever since.

Comment: Is it a pre-installed VPS server? Those often come with only the bare minimum packages pre-installed (I had one without even `man`).